# Opening a file with french characters using StreamReader showing wrong incorrect data

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, stream

I have a file with the following text in: `SignOut,déconnectez`.

When I use the following code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        list.Add(line); // Add to list.

}
```

I get this back: `"Sign Out,d�connectez,"`

I thought that opening the file with `Encoding.UTF8` would be enough but it doesn't seem to do anything. Could someone point me in the right direction to open a file that may contain non standard characters please?

Comment: Use different encoding..

Comment: I have tried all the available ones in `Encoding.???` but none seem to work. It also doesn't explain why UTF8 isn't enough becase AFAIK it should be.

Comment: Well you need to *know* the encoding used. You shouldn't just *guess* at it. Where did the file come from? I suspect this just *isn't* UTF-8. What does the binary data for the file look like on that line?

Comment: It's a user submitted file. It will be a plain CSV though.

Comment: @webnoob: Well you'll still need to know the encoding. There are ways to attempt to determine that heuristically, but that's a slightly different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Right Ok, that makes sense. I "assumed" as it was plain CSV it wouldn't be a problem but when I think about it more, it makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: Added the same thing as answer - removed it. Why adding this as comment when it is the only answer to the problem? By the way - CSV is not the encoding - a plain CSV still has an encoding.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes I understand, poor choice of words.

Comment: @Marcus - Why remove the answer? I was going to accept it ...

Comment: @webnoob: _"Make sure your file is in the same encoding"_ is not really an answer but a comment.

Comment: I have decided to allow the user to upload a .xls file instead and use the OleDb drivers to load it. That way it's windows problem :)

Comment: GetEncoding(437) is usually a decent guess.  Used by old MS-Dos programs in Western Europe.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
```